# My iOS app worked well under IPv6, but it was wrong to connect to XMPP. The Android didn't has the error

Tags: ios, xmpp, ipv6, xmppframework

The picture is testing the domain name of the server. I connect XMPP via port 5222, failed for the reason:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain 
Code=51 "Network is unreachable" 
UserInfo={
    NSLocalizedDescription=Network is unreachable,
    NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error in connect() function}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `XMPPStream.m` file, go to `init` function, just below the line

```
asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:xmppQueue];
```

add the following line

```
[asyncSocket setPreferIPv4OverIPv6:NO];
```

chat will work in both IPV4 & IPV6 then